# Horizontal line between items in flutter web is not shown in firefox web browser

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I developed a flutter web application. It works perfectly in other browsers except for the Firefox browser.
I have a list of items between each item I added a horizontal line using

```
Container(
  width: double.infinity,
  height: 0.7,
  color: Color(0xffEBEBEB)                       
)
```

[image]

But in firefox lines between some items are not visible

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you have the height as a decimal. The height is in number of pixels. When you use decimals you can get rounding errors. That it rounds to 0 in some cases and 1 in other. Just give it a height of 1 like

```
height: 1,
```

You will see that it still looks the same, because they where actually rendered with height 1 for the places where you do see it. Using values that are not whole numbers doesn't make sense in most cases